# What should I do when my question do not have any answer..

Tags: feature-request, answers, unanswered-questions

**This Question is not intended to grab answers.. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3478/how-to-grab-users-attention-on-an-old-question is not a duplicate of this**

My Question is..

I have posted some questions asking for clarification regarding my idea...

[Is $(tr(A))^n\geq n^n \det(A)$ for a symmetric positive definite matrix $A\in M_{n\times n} (\mathbb{R})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552780/is-tran-geq-nn-deta-for-a-symmetric-positive-definite-matrix-a-in-m)

[Question on Riemann sums](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556805/question-on-riemann-sums)

[representation of points of continuity of a function $f :\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575923/representation-of-points-of-continuity-of-a-function-f-mathbbr-rightarrow)

[Finitely generated group has only finitely many subgroups of given index](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494402/finitely-generated-group-has-only-finitely-many-subgroups-of-given-index)

[Series convergence Question ( TIFR GS $2010$)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/570197/series-convergence-question-tifr-gs-2010)

[$\int f^2(x)dx=0$ if $\int f(x) x^n=0 $ for all $n=1,2,3,\dots$ (TIFR GS ($2012$))](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/572303/int-f2xdx-0-if-int-fx-xn-0-for-all-n-1-2-3-dots-tifr-gs-2012)

These questions do not have any answers..

My intention is not to grab answers... in these questions I am explaining my answer and asking for conformation... so there is no question of getting new answers for this...

As it would left unanswered should I just delete these questions (I do not want to) or write Something in answer box and accept it?

Comment: @JChau : My intention is not to grab answers.... please read my question again...

Comment: Could you clarify what you understand "answer" to mean?  Here, if the question is asking for confirmation, then confirmation is the "answer" to the question, i.e. if you are still looking for confirmation of correctness, then you still want your questions to be "answered". Either you or I are confusing the distinction between "answer" and "solution" or "proof".

Comment: It seems like you're showing [too much effort](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13058/too-much-effort-shown).

Comment: @GitGud : So what am i supposed to do now?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Who knows...?

Comment: @GitGud fine :D

Comment: Maybe http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4597/best-way-of-asking-check-my-proof-questions and some discussions linked there are worth looking at.

Answer (score 3):

(speaking in the abstract...)

If you have an actual *answer* to the question, it would be good write up the answer and accept it.

If you don't have an answer, it's fine to leave them; maybe someone will come along and answer it in the future, or others might find the comment useful. If you want them answered, you could try putting a bounty on the questions.

Comment: I guess you have not understood my question.... My question is...in these questions i am explaining my answer and asking for conformation... so there is no question of getting new answers for this...